# How to know if an ECC public key is y or -y

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, finite-field, secp256k1

I'm a beginner still learning how ecc works... And i think I understand that in secp256k1 public keys there is something called addictive and negative inverse for example **private key:- 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001** is additive inverse and it's public key is **0279be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798**

The negative inverse of **0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001** is **0379be667ef9dcbbac55a06295ce870b07029bfcdb2dce28d959f2815b16f81798** and it's private key is **fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140**

what I understand is for the private :- **0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001** it's public key is x, y but for its inverse it's x, -y is that right? I'm curious to know if there is a way to know if a public key is falling in additive inverse or negative inverse? If yes can someone show me how it can be done with a similar explanation with no much math involved

**EDIT**

First let me tell you how I understand secp256k1 public keys *(it's my own understand might seem a bit stupid)*  so how I see ecc is from private **1** all the way upto private key **7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff5d576e7357a4501ddfe92f46681b20a0**  is additive inverse

and from private key **7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff5d576e7357a4501ddfe92f46681b20a1** all the way upto

**fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140**

i see it as negative inverse

Now what I mean by -y is like the above example private key 1 has a public thats a positive y  and the public key of the inverse of private key 1 is -y (private key :-**fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364140**

Comment: [How to determine the prefix of a SECP256K1 compressed public key](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/108091/18298) and [How to expand elliptic curve public key from compressed form?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/100606/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka the posts that you have shared still don't answer my question can you please help me understand the above EDIT  better